# How to get unigrams (words) from a list in python?

Tags: python

Input is list1=['water vapor','evaporation','carbon dioxide','sunlight','green plants']

Output should be

```
list1=['evaporation','sunlight']
for i in list1:
    " " not in i
    print i

False - water vapor
True - evaporation
False - carbon dioxide
True - sunlight
False - green plants
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Yes i have tried. But not getting this output

Comment: Please post what code you've tried and your results.

Comment: You are getting downvotes because you have not posted any code try posting your code

Comment: I guess that you want to remove items that contains more than one word. What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't those strings containing a single word, e.g. "evaporation" & "sunlight" unigrams? It seems to me that you want to *retain* the unigrams, not remove them.

You can do that using a list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['water vapor','evaporation','carbon dioxide','sunlight','green plants']
unigrams = [word for word in list1 if ' ' not in word]

>>> print unigrams
['evaporation', 'sunlight']
```

This assumes that words are separated by a one or more spaces. This might be an oversimplification as to what constitutes a n-gram for n > 1 as different whitespace characters could delimit words e.g. tab, new line, various whitespace unicode code points, etc. You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) :

```
import re

list1 = ['water vapor','evaporation','carbon dioxide','sunlight','green plants', 'word with\ttab', 'word\nword', 'abcd\refg']
unigram_pattern = re.compile('^\S+$')    # string contains only non-whitespace chars
unigrams = [word for word in list1 if unigram_pattern.match(word)]

>>> print unigrams
['evaporation', 'sunlight']
```

The pattern `^\S+$` says to match from the beginning of a string all non-whitespace characters until the end of the string.

If you need to support unicode spaces you can specify the unicode flag when compiling the pattern:

```
list1.extend([u'punctuation\u2008space', u'NO-BREAKu\u00a0SPACE'])
unigram_pattern = re.compile('^\S+$', re.UNICODE)
unigrams = [word for word in list1 if unigram_pattern.match(word)]

>>> print unigrams
['evaporation', 'sunlight']
```

Now it will also filter out those strings that contain unicode whitespace, e.g. non-break space (U+00A0) and punctuation space (U+2008).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove elements from a list based on a condition, you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) or [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

You get the idea about checking for non-unigram words: `" " in word`.

Basically, if you want to construct a new list using a for loop, you can write something like:

```
new_list = []
for word in words:
    if " " in word:  # This is not an unigram word
        new_list.append(word)
```

This can be simpler, thanks to Python syntax:

```
new_list = [word for word in words if " " in word]
```

Alternatively:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda word: " " in word, words))
```

Both will return the list of non-unigram words, as stated in the title of your question (even if your example returns unigram words...)